# fenics did not show figure . NameError: name interactive is not defined

Tags: fenics

I installed fenics on windows subsystem for linux to do my homework.I am trying to test fenics. So I use ft01_possion.py on the tutorial.

```
from fenics import *

# Create mesh and define function space
mesh = UnitSquareMesh(8, 8)
V = FunctionSpace(mesh, 'P', 1)

# Define boundary conditions
u_D = Expression('1 + x[0]*x[0] + 2*x[1]*x[1]', degree = 2)

def boundary(x, on_boundary):
      return on_boundary

bc = DirichletBC(V, u_D, boundary)

# Define variational problem
u = TrialFunction(V)
v = TestFunction(V)
f = Constant(-6.0)
a = dot(grad(u), grad(v))*dx
L = f*v*dx

# Compute solution
u = Function(V)
solve(a == L, u, bc)

# Plot solution and mesh
plot(u)
plot(mesh)
interactive()
```

It did not show the figure.
the error i am getting is:

```
Solving linear variational problem.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ft01_poisson.py", line 29, in <module>
interactive()
NameError: name 'interactive' is not defined
```

I have tried to reinstall the newest version of fenics without success.

While the print out of the error values work, the NameError prevents the plots from being shown.

Answer (score 4):

Some Fenics examples are unfortunately out of date. Please see the following [GitHub post](https://github.com/hplgit/fenics-tutorial/issues/42).

Change 'interactive()' to

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

this will show your results.

Comment: Thanks, https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-52462-7.pdf 1.4 "Obtaining the software" says "This tutorial was prepared
for and tested with FEniCS version 2016.2." BTW. That's what they get for publishing docs through Springer PDFs >:-)

Comment: Just comment `interactive()` & only use `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Errors are shown as follows:
error_L2 = 0.008235098073354827
error_max = 1.3322676295501878e-15
But there is :NameError: name 'interactive' is not defined, probably this error is not affecting the results